# Display port security state of an HP 3COM 5120 switch port

Tags: networking, security, switch

I'm using an HP-A5120-24G-SI switch and I'm asking how to obtain the current state of the port-security module for a certain port. I'm able to view the current settings using

```
display port-security
```

Output:

```
...

GigabitEthernet1/0/2 is link-down
  Port mode is secure
  NeedToKnow mode is NeedToKnowWithMulticast
  Intrusion Protection mode is BlockMacAddress
  Max MAC address number is 1
  Stored MAC address number is 1
  Authorization is permitted

...
```

You see, the port mode is *secure* and the *Intrusion Protection mode* was set *BlockMacAddress*, but how can I check which mac addresses has been blocked on that interface?

---

I'm asking because on ProCurve switches I can simply execute the following command to display the state:

```
show interfaces brief IFACE_NUMBER
```

Output (for iface 2):

```
                | Intrusion                           MDI   Flow  Bcast 
Port  Type      | Alert     Enabled Status Mode       Mode  Ctrl  Limit 
----- --------- + --------- ------- ------ ---------- ----- ----- ------
2     100/1000T | No        Yes     Up     1000FDx    MDI   off   0
```

You can clearly see whether the "Intrusion Alert" is set or not. I would like to find a comparable command for the HP-5120.